# How to change Byobu prompt from ">" to "$"?

Tags: byobu

From the time I use Linux, the prompt ends with `#` for root and with `$` for common users.

On the latest LTS version, this changed to `>` for common users under Byobu.

Question 1: Why?

Question 2: How to fix it, without manually messing with `$PS1`?

Comment: You might need to address this to the Byobu people.  They have a stack exchange at http://stackexchange.com/search?q=byobu

Comment: @CharlesGreen - with that all you really get it the [tag at SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/byobu) and [the one here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/byobu)....

Comment: Huh.  That's the link I found at the byobu support website.  http://byobu.co/support.html

Comment: I'm happy to answer Byobu questions here, or on any other StackExchange site.  I actively monitor all of them for questions tagged 'bybou'.

Comment: Thanks @DustinKirkland. I asked here because I saw lots of answers with "Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of Byobu.", so asking here seemed acceptable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can trivially disable (or enable) [Byobu's](http://byobu.co) custom prompt by running:

```
byobu-disable-prompt
```

and

```
byobu-enable-prompt
```

To answer your question, "why?", I direct you to this blog post where I introduced the functionality:

- http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2013/08/ubuntu-fun-with-ps1.html

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: I ended up changing [here](https://github.com/dustinkirkland/byobu/blob/master/usr/share/byobu/profiles/bashrc#L30) directly. I would expect it to be optional anyway. Well, thanks for the blogpost link.